# LOGSTASH: How to setup logstash to get all query's data not only a part of it?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I've a database table which contains 400+ records, but each time, I use logstash and JDBC it only gets 126 records. I tried many times with different indices each time, but still the 126 only retrieving.

Here is the output configurations:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        -
        -
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from xfailure"
    }
}
output {
elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   manage_template => false
   index => "test_predictions"
   document_id => "%{id}"
}
}
```

When I check the number of rows, I found that it has 400+ records here is the select statment:

```
SELECT * FROM xfailure;
```

here is a sample of the record columns:

```
id|modified|x_url|x_id|correlation_id|links|code|description|explanation|tr_id
```

Whem I create an index on Kibanna, I used the timestamp as time field, but the number of hits is just 162 hits!

Comment: Are there errors in logstah or elasticsearch logs? Have you predefined a index mapping or are you relying on auto-mapping?

Comment: @ibexit `index => "test_predictions"` If you mean by indexing maping specifying the index to store the data in then yes I specified it. I also tried with and without specifying the document_id.

Comment: Nah, elastic creates an mapping for each index, its a kind of a schema where all the fields and datatypes are defined. If you do not specify one, elastic tries to guess it based on the incoming docs. And if there are documents not matching the auto guessed schema aka mapping, they will be not indexed.

Comment: @ibexit I am retrieving data from a postgresql database table so I think no chance for having more than one schema.

Comment: It is enough to have a mixed field where strings or numbers are pissible. The firdt dic with a number comes in, elastics guess for the mapping will be number and then, later another doc comes in with a string as this fields value - bam! Have a look into logs, maybe it is sth different...

Comment: @ibexit I tried with output as CSV, and it also gets the first 126 record!

Comment: @ibexit It worked after specifying the fields instead of SELECT *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this which is specifying each field so by changin the sql query from:

```
SELECT * FROM xfailure;
```

to

```
SELECT field_1 as field_1, field_2 as field_2 FROM xfailure;
```

And it now works fine.